# Using qsort to organize vec of struct (C)

Tags: c, vector, struct

I'm trying to use qsort to organize a vec. But I'm having trouble with the `cmpfunc`. The vec is a vec of structs. The struct is very simple, it has a string and a number. And I want to organize by the number.

```
    int cmpfunc (const void *a, const void *b)
    {
        Item i = *((Item*) a);
        Item j = *((Item*) b);
        if (i->acc < j->acc)
            return 1;
        if (i->acc > j->acc)
            return -1;
    }
```

`qsort(vec, max, sizeof(Item), cmpfunc);`

I get this `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }`

Comment: regarding your warning, what do you think your function returns if the test values are *equivalent*, and thusly *neither* of those `return` statements fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only have a return inside of if statements you need a return at the bottom of the function that it can always get to no matter what:

```
int cmpfunc (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    Item i = *((Item*) a);
    Item j = *((Item*) b);
    if (i->acc < j->acc)
        return 1;
    if (i->acc > j->acc)
        return -1;
    return 0; 
}
```

or this will work too:

```
int cmpfunc (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    Item i = *((Item*) a);
    Item j = *((Item*) b);
    if (i->acc < j->acc)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Note the latter *can* trigger integer underflow. Typically I do something like this: `return (j->acc < i->acc) ? -1 : i->acc < j->acc;`, which will cover all three cases of lesser, greater, and equal, returning -1, 1, and 0 respectively.